# Create a blockchain.com wallet using the api

Tags: javascript, api, blockchain

I want to create a blockchain.com wallet using their api, I have been given a api key but I am not to experienced with using api's and have no idea how to proceed.

I have searched around and can find no examples on how to set this up. Would anyone be able to show me a quick example on how to create a new wallet using the blockchain.com api with javascript?

https://www.blockchain.com/api/blockchain_wallet_api

Comment: You have to make an http request with the required parameters, either via a GET or via a POST. There's plenty of guides around on how to do just that, now that you know what to look for :)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca ok I have done that, but the other problem is where do I install the npm and do this '$ blockchain-wallet-service start --port 3000'? Im running this on phonegap

Comment: So you're asking us for a tutorial on how to install a piece of software, the required dependencies to develop for it and how to then write your own software? That's quite broad, don't you think? And before you say "no, I just want to know if there's a guide somewhere", well, that's off-topic as well `:-/`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca im just asking where do i install the npm to and start it.

Comment: "the npm" is a package manager. You install it wherever you normally install software on your machine. If you're asking where to install a particular pacakge, you can install it wherever you want. I'm not sure I understand what doubts you are having.